# Check the html checkbox with object value in Angular2

Tags: angular

I have a checkbox as below

```
<input type="checkbox" name="sizecb[]" value="{{searchResult.id}}" [(ngModel)]="searchResult.state">
```

However, when the searchResult.state is received from database, the checkbox does not gets checked.

```
 this.HomeDataService.getResult().subscribe((search: Project.Models.ResultModel[]) => {
            this.searchResults = search;
```

Comment: what does the `sizecb[]` caontain..?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you tring add *checked* attribute to your input? You can do this in this way:

```
<input type="checkbox" [checked]="searchResult.state" ...>
```